# Not able to make my website mobile friendly, even when it looks ok on mobile, what I'm missing?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, responsive-design, user-friendly

Not able to make my website mobile friendly, even when it looks ok on mobile, what I'm missing?
- I made sure that the buttons are readable,
- The spacing between them is decent,
- There is no content wider than the screen

But I'm still not able to pass the mobile friendly test for my home page: https://www.lsdev.biz/

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Your site visually looks alright on mobile, however there are a few technical issues that could be improved.

According to [Google Pagespeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lsdev.biz%2F&tab=mobile) things to help make your site mobile friendly are to

- Eliminate render blocking JavaScript and CSS
- Leverage browser caching
- Reducing server response time

The link above has details on what specifically needs fixing, and how to fix them.

[image: Screenshot of Pagespeed Insights]

Answer (score 0):

Mobile friendly is not only about showing good on mobile devices, other factors like speed will definitely influence.

Your website has way more requests than necessary in `head` which decrease the performance, try to cut some of them and put js files at the end of the page.

Wish it could help